# A good solution for user authentication from iPhone app at a PHP server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, authentication, nsurlconnection

I have been trying to implement a secure user authentication for an iPhone app. I am pretty much a newbie. I saw many code snippets and suggestions for different ways, and some seemed out dated. In the present scenario, what would be a good option? JSON? ASIHTTPRequest?

Till now, I couldn't find a proper solution for this. I am finding a bit difficult to integrate different ideas and come up with a solution to suit my need. Would be great if someone could share a sample code or at least point me to a solution posted somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Tony

Answer (score 1):

What kind of user authentication does your server have? You could use Basic Auth for authentication, which pretty much means sending the [`Authorization`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) headers with every request.

[ASIHTTPRequest has functionality enabling basic auth](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) and even presenting a login dialog, if you're OK with using that (the project's just been discontinued).

You would obviously need to [implement basic authentication on your server](http://www.google.se/search?gcx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=stackoverflow%20enable%20basic%20auth%20on%20server) as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have control over the server. What I basically need is to perform an authentication using "POST". I am very new to Objective-C, so any sample code will be a great help. I need the part where the request(NSData, NSDictionary) is composed.

Comment: If you're using ASIHTTPRequest, you'll only need to set the credentials using [request setUsername:@"foo"] and [request setPassword:@"bar"]. And if you want to use their built-in authentication dialog, just set [request setShouldPresentAuthenticationDialog:YES] as well.

If you're using some other framework, the code's probably very similar to [request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:@"your encoded authorization string"].

Answer (score 0):

I used this to successfully authenticate a user with a remote PHP server from an iOS app. A bit late, but it may help someone:

```
-(void)saveNewUserDetails{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.username.text forKey:@"userName"];
    [SSKeychain setPassword:self.pwd.text forService:@"MiniCEXReporting" account:self.username.text]; //store securely rather than in NSUserDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}

-(void) makeConnection{
    self.activityIndicator.hidden=NO;
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSString *userString=self.username.text;
    postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://someURLhereWithUsernameappended/%@", userString]]];

    //for the real thing
    //postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://somsis-dev.leeds.ac.uk/api/minicex/%@", self.username.text]]];

    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];    
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:self.username.text
                                                                    password:self.pwd.text
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"authentication failure username -%@- with password -%@-", self.username.text, self.pwd.text);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication Error"
                                                        message:@"Please check your username and password"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        self.activityIndicator.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```